# XPath query: parsing multiple paths using the same query (Cross Apply / .nodes() )

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have a rather big and structured XML receipt which one I want to parse into a relational database. There are some equal structures on different levels, so it'd be very good to parse them using the same SQL statement. Like:

```
DECLARE @XMLPath varchar(127)
SET @XMLPath = 'atag/btag/item'

INSERT INTO XMLReadItems
  SELECT ci.InvoiceID, 
    T.c.value('productname[1]', 'varchar(63)') AS InvoiceTarget,
    T.c.value('unit[1]', 'varchar(15)') AS Unit,
FROM @XMLItems ci CROSS APPLY XMLCol.nodes(*[local-name()=sql:variable("@XMLPath")]') T(c)
```

Where `@XMLPath` could be a string from a variable or even a field from a table (what about using `sql:column()`?). But any of them I couldn't make work.
I can only use a static string in `XMLCol.nodes()`.

Comment: "But any of them I couldn't make work." How did they not work - did you get an error message? What message? Did you get a wrong result? What result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can construct XQuery parameter dynamically as it is limited to *literal string* only. See what [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) says about the parameter of `nodes()` XML method  :

> XQuery
>
> **Is a string literal, an XQuery expression**. If the query expression constructs nodes, these constructed nodes are exposed in the resulting rowset. If the query expression results in an empty sequence, the rowset will be empty. If the query expression statically results in a sequence that contains atomic values instead of nodes, a static error is raised.

Forcing to pass SQL variable to `nodes()` method would trigger error :

> The argument 1 of the XML data type method "nodes" must be a string literal.

The trick you're trying to implement only works for *matching element by name* dynamically, not *constructing the entire XPath* dynamically. For example, the following should work fine to shred on `item` elements :

```
SET @elementName = 'item'

SELECT .....
FROM @XMLItems ci 
CROSS APPLY XMLCol.nodes('//*[local-name()=sql:variable("@elementName")]') T(c)
```

In the end there is no workaround to this limitation as far as I can see, unless you want to go farther to construct the entire query dynamically (see: [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)).

Comment: So if I understand well there's no way to use a dynamic expression instead of a static string. No trick.
The only possibility is to construct the whole query as a string (arrgh, I really hate that... :( )

Comment: Yes. As mentioned above, there is a trick for a *very limited scenario* (not very useful generally)